# How to get latest calendar events in Liferay

Tags: java, events, calendar, liferay-6

I want to retrieve latest two events from calendar Event table in Liferay.

I have tried this

```java
List<CalEvent> cl = CalEventLocalServiceUtil.getCalEvents(CalEventLocalServiceUtil.getCalEventsCount()-2, CalEventLocalServiceUtil.getCalEventsCount());
```

I am getting two events but I want latest two based on their modified date.

How can I get the latest two events based on their modified date?

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add that type of statement in service.xml

`<order by="desc">
    <order-column name="modifieddate" />
</order>`

You Will get your result.